# Opera 24 Developer for Linux will not launch

Tags: permissions, opera

Today I downloaded the much anticipated, for me at least, Opera 24 for Linux. Very unfortunately I get an error and cannot launch Opera unless I do it as root. The following is returned unless I run as root:

```
opera-developer
[0623/111432:ERROR:chrome_import_controller.cc(122)] Could not create a copy of Bookmarks, will not import.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[0100/000000:FATAL:zygote_linux.cc(368)] Failed to synchronise with parent zygote process
[0623/111432:ERROR:chrome_import_controller.cc(122)] Could not create a copy of Bookmarks, will not import.
[0623/111432:ERROR:chrome_import_controller.cc(122)] Could not create a copy of Bookmarks, will not import.
[0100/000000:FATAL:zygote_linux.cc(368)] Failed to synchronise with parent zygote process
```

When successfully executed nothing more then a `IBUS-WARNING` is returned stating that `/home/viktor/.config/ibus/bus` isn't owned by root.

I run Opera 24.0.1537.0 Developer on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Opera on the other hand cannot recognize some part of my system; `System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (x86_64; Unknown)`.

I understand of course that this is a development release of Opera and I shouldn't expect it to work on all machines and it shouldn't work perfectly. Although I still find that, since the software itself work flawlessly, you should be able to remove the need for root privileges.

-- EDIT --

I forgot to mention it here on AskUbuntu but I got in touch with a developer who promised everything would be alright in the next update. I can now launch Opera without trouble but no settings/addons will be launched, even though they are stored. Launching with root will load all addons and all settings will be loaded (that's how I know they were saved).

I figured this question is now outdated and no longer relevant and I'm planning to make another one shortly. If you think you know the answer to my new problems you are ofc welcome to post an answer.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Opera. You should report it to the developers. I'm curious where you got this copy of Opera. I don't see it on thier website.

Comment: I've reported it as a bug. Here's the link I got: http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/06/opera-24-linux-released-developer-stream/?utm_medium=sm&utm_source=googleplus&utm_campaign=linux_social&utm_content=o24_release

Comment: This is being followed up in a bug. But quick question; have you installed a custom kernel? And/or did you modify permissions in any way, especially the setuid+root opera_sandbox binary? Do 'opera-developer --no-sandbox' run?

Comment: I have not installed a custom kernel and I haven't modified any permissions whatsoever. 'opera-developer --no-sandbox' return the same errors with the addition of explaining it's running without SUID sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

got the same issue with ubuntu 14.04, you have to start opera once with the following command:

```
opera-developer --with-feature:first-run-import=false &
```

see http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2014/06/opera-24-linux-released-developer-stream/#comment-1452086964

Comment: The problem about this is that Opera will not save any settings or import settings saved previously. The browser launched successfully anyways, but as said with default settings :(

Comment: that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

An updated version of opera developer was made available today - run the Software Updater or from the Terminal:

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

and the new version will be installed.